# Upgrade Nifi and Registry running on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-nifi, docker-image

I have a 2 node nifi cluster running on a kubernetes cloud environment, along with a registry. Currently the cluster and registry are running 1.16.2 versions. I want to update them to 1.17.0, and was wondering if there's any steps I need to take?

I have a yaml file for both nifi and registry configured to our needs and use them to deploy on to the cloud. Am I overthinking this? Wondering if I could just point to the new image versions?

Tried a simple image version change, and everything works fine on local instance. But not sure if this is the best practice.

Comment: You actually just need to follow the migration guide. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/nifi/migration+guidance

I would recommend to do a backup before upgrading. In case of something breaks, you're still able to restore and go back to previous version.

Comment: I looked at the migration guide and it seems that none of my current flows and any scripts will be affected. Would I just simply point to this new image version then?

Comment: Yes. It's that simple in case of there is nothing to migrate. Still, i would recommend a backup before any upgrades.

Comment: You should post your solution then what you've done. In case of someone else is looking for upgrading Nifi.

Comment: Thanks Manuel, appreciate the assurance haha!